# Is there any interdependence between asanas and pranayamas?

Tags: yoga, pranayama, asana

Asana is a prerequisite for Pranayama.

There are several types of Pranayama and Asana.

Is the effect same in the following two cases

1. Doing any type Pranayama with any Asana
2. Doing a particular type of Pranayama with a particular Asana

If the effect is different, then an example of achieving something with *only* a particular type of Pranayama with a particular type of Asana can be an answer.

Comment: Take a look at this answer - https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/28119

Comment: It is not required to do a particular type of Pranayama by sitting in a particular Asana. The same Asana will work equally well for each Pranayama. Recommended Asanas are Padma, Vira, Swastika etc..